# How can I re-enable button that has been disabled and have no idea how it was disabled?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

for whatever reason, the "Add to Cart" `<button>` on the woocommerce site I have been working on is disabled. I have not done this and I am wondering not only how this could have happened, but secondly how to correct it? 
Everything was working properly last night when I went to bed, but today woke up to this certain issue.

If a user goes to http://gearbags.com/store/shop/ and selects `quick view` after they hover over the image, that add to cart `button` works as it should. Similarly for some strange reason, in different browsers you can add to cart from the actual product [page](http://gearbags.com/store/product/lxfb30/) but if you refresh the page and try to add more items, you get the same error as mentioned above about the button not working at all.

I am extremely confused as to what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Here] is an image to display what is going on.

You can view the site at the following [link](http://gearbags.com/store/product/lxfb30/).

Comment: remove `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: The problem is, I haven't added that anywhere in the code. It has just magically appeared. I have no access to it. As you can see on the right "User Agent Stylesheet"

Comment: You - or your orgnaization -  should have the means to investigate this. In particular, you should have - or be able to setup - a testing enviroment (on private network) where you can run the service. There would add debug logs, or other means to investigate the case. Regardless, you would have saved yourself some trouble if you were using version control. If you are using version control, and the code is unchanged - this means that the problem was already there, but triggered by the browser or other element outside of your control. Review your code - we cannot access the server  code anwyay.

Comment: @Theraot I have this set up and understand the process. This is why I am here. Everything has been working fine for a year now. Now all of a sudden this issue. Code hasn't been edited for weeks. No debug errors. No server errors. No errors at all except a few missing bootstrap files in the console.

Comment: @jshuadvd the code hasn't been edited, but did it change (corrupted, sabotaged, hacked, ...)? - Anyway, you want to know where a button was disabled. It could have been disabled by javascript or it could have been served disabled. Check which is the case. If it is client side, you could search for "disabled" on the served page, or debug step by step. Server side? Find where the button is emited and review the code - add logs if you need to know what branch of the code is running. I would expect that this is a change in browser or similar, maybe you were using some old javascript quirk?

Comment: @Theraot it hasn't changed. Hasn't been hacked or anything like that. The site has the most expensive version of site lock. It is distributed over different cDns so that if one goes down others are not affected and pop up in its place. I have scoured the code to find disabled to no avail. It could e some quirk, but I don't see why it would all of a sudden just stop working. There would be some kind of deprivation warning or something, I would assume. As for the browser, haven't updated it so indict see why that would be it. :(

Comment: Debug procedure: disable all plugins and revert theme to default. re-enabled everything bit by bit until you isolate the problem. Also make sure all caches are cleared. For what it's worth, I am not having any issue adding your products to the cart.

Comment: @helgatheviking thank you. Really? Quick question, if on a product page and you add an item to the cart.  Once the cart is updated, can you add more of the same product?

Comment: @jshuadvd that sounds like the bug was introduced but not catched in testing. Can you find an old version that works (from your version control) and compare the diff? that may narrow the search. Yes, if it was something deprecated, there would have been a warning. Idk if this is the case, but some organization disable warnings in production. Also if it was only in browser it may easily have gone undetected. Similary, if it works on some browsers you may consider to put logs statements in javascript to see how they differ from browser to browser - I also agree on disabling plugins.

Comment: the `title` of the button html says what it is...

Comment: @Theraot ok thanks. Going to go back through and see what I come up with.

Comment: @Reigel can you expand? Bc all items are stoked plenty.

Comment: I see the problem with variable products: you have to set the variations before the add to cart button is enabled. However, you when you  have all default attributes the variation should be selected and the button enabled. Again, I would suggest going through the procedure I recommended before. If you can still produce it then it is possibly a bug in WooCommerce. I can't test it now myself because I'm going to bed!

Comment: `Sorry this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.` Maybe you have a combination that has no price, or can not be sold for whatever reasons... out of stock perhaps? should be in your Product Data settings > Variations